# Automator application needs to ignore all files that aren't EPS

Tags: finder, applescript, automator

I've made an application that I drop EPS files on and it makes two copies and renames them and transfers them to SMB shares.

But sometimes when I have more than one file selected in other windows, Finder passes multiple files onto Automator. All I really need it to use are EPS files, ignoring others and passing the EPS files on to automator for renaming.

I pass variables onto an applescript for if statements. My first attempt:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    if (input as text) does not contain ".eps" then
        tell application "Auto 45" to quit
    else

    end if

    return input

end run
```

Then I realized that this doesn't do anything about multiple files. If it finds .eps anywhere in all files combined into a single variable, it simply passes all kinds of junk files through.

I tried to use this if statement instead:

```
tell application finder
    if name extension of (input) is "eps" then
        #if (input as text) is equal to type "eps" then
        return input
    else
        nothing
    end if

end tell
```

This code doesn't work even though it compiles, nor does this solve the problem of checking multiple inputs. I'm using the Mavericks version of Automator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for your problem is the **Filter Finder Items** action.

Just add it to your workflow before your **AppleScript** Action.

Comment: That line compiles but I can't get it to pass the correct information back to Automator:


`on run {input, parameters}
 global myEPS
 
 set myEPS to every item of input whose name contains ".eps"
 
 return myEPS
 
end run`

Comment: I found a better way to do this, see my edit !

Comment: BAM! That does it. Don't even need the applescript anymore. I may include it to shut down if the input is blank or to give a warning.